# HttpClient.getAsync() Out of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, json, out-of-memory, dotnet-httpclient

I have a function that gets a large amount of JSON from a web service. This data can be large sometimes, gigabytes. My call looks like this.

```
        try
        {
            using (var httpClient = NewHttpClient())
            {
                var response = httpClient.GetAsync(endpoint).Result;
                return response;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //Do Stuff
        }
```

When the data is large, this throws an out of memory exception. I believe it is because the response message is actually bigger than HttpResponseMessage will allow it to be. Is there a way to get only pieces of the message in a time? I am sure it has been done before but I was unable to find anything with google and/or slashdot. Thanks for advice in advance.

Comment: I think it's not because it is bigger than HttpResponseMessage but because your computer cannot allocate enough RAM to hold all that data.

Comment: Where is the exception thrown? I would expect this to work just fine but the reading of the data to be the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just get the stream and write it to a file so that you can process it later,

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
    stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream)
}
```

Comment: Or better yet, use the overload of GetAsync() that takes a **HttpCompletionOption** parameter: ```var response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)```